# Matrix File Upload not displaying contents of directory, upload silently fails

Tags: matrix, assets, file-uploads, file-manager, server

EE v2.5.5 - Build Date: 20121220
Assets 2.0.5
Matrix 2.5.3
Safecracker 2.1 (not sure if relevant)

I am using (but was not the original developer for) a multisite EE installation. In each installation I have the same channel, field group (Matrix) and identically named image upload path. However, on one of the sites I cannot get images to actually upload to the image upload directory or appear in the file upload dialog, pictured below.

[image: file upload not indicating directory. After the file upload progress bar disappears, the form still looks like this]

Comment: Hi, Michael, are you sure you have a file upload preference set up on that site?  Also, I'd recommend upgrading to Assets 2.1.3 before much more troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks. The original dev figured it out -- I hadn't run update index to finish setting up the upload destination. Just a newbie error. :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer! I'd recommend posting this as a full answer and accepting it - and thank you for the update!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that I hadn't run Update Index to finish setting up the upload destination. I had only created the upload destination and created the matrix field in channel field groups. Hope this helps someone else.