# Assets Uploading Fails

Tags: assets

This is very similar to [Matrix File Upload not displaying contents of directory, upload silently fails](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/10500/matrix-file-upload-not-displaying-contents-of-directory-upload-silently-fails)

I've just begun to work on an existing MSM site.
I set up some new upload directories, added them to my bootstrap array.

I had the faded upload button, etc.
When I updated my indexes, it returned to normal but the upload still just silently failed.

I updated Assets to the latest version because I read in the changelog "Failed uploads now display a proper error message."
Upon trying the upload again, I had to laugh... the alert simply said "undefined".

When I try to upload to an *existing* upload directory, I can't upload either, but the error says: "Could not upload the file - server returned an unexpected response. Please check the server settings."

In my web developer toolbar, the network tab shows a 200 OK POST to `?folder=35&ACT=36&qqfile=test.jpg`.
ACT36 in my DB is Assets_mcp/upload_file.

All the folders have 777 permissions.
I believe all the file paths are correct because I can *see* files in Assets, I just can't upload.

What am I missing?

Comment: Hey Jason,

What's the AJAX response to that ACT36 request?

Comment: Ah. PHP error: `Message: fopen(/path/to/system/expressionengine/cache/assets/tmp_storage/assets_tmp_519f7323ab4c24.57700139.jpg) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied` My cache folder wasn't writable. D'oh. Thank you!

Comment: Hah, well, there you go :)

Comment: I'm not seeing the system folder anywhere -- can someone tell me where to find it?

Comment: @Margaret EE's default location is installed into /system/... The best practice is to rename this directory to something obscure... Change you admin.php or index.php file to see what it was renamed to. Details are here: https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/best_practices.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to make sure my /system/expressionengine/cache/ directories were writable.

Checking the AJAX response in the web developer toolbar showed me a PHP error saying it couldn't write to the file.